"An exception was thrown attempting to enter NODAEMONS" error on Guidewire ClaimsCenter startup
Working on Guidewire ClaimCenter (Jasper release), startup goes fine until I reach the end of it and the following error is reported:
2024-05-16 12:38:47,834 INFO Reading config file: C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\claimcenter\claimcenter\modules\configuration\config\config.xml
2024-05-16 12:38:47,883 WARN Parameter InputMaskPlaceholderCharacter is deprecated with the following message: Obsolete - does nothing.
2024-05-16 12:38:47,883 WARN Parameter TreeViewRefresh is deprecated with the following message: Obsolete - does nothing.
2024-05-16 12:38:47,895 INFO Parsing C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\claimcenter\claimcenter\modules\configuration\config\suite\suite-config.xml
2024-05-16 12:38:47,928 INFO Memory usage: 614.696 MB used (both active and stale objects), 117.302 MB free, 732.000 MB total, 4096.000 MB max. --  Please read 'Memory usage logging' in the System Administration Guide for information on how to interpret these numbers.
2024-05-16 12:38:49,800 INFO Plugin configuration loaded from C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\claimcenter\claimcenter\modules\configuration\config\plugin\plugin-config.xml
2024-05-16 12:38:58,334 WARN The key 'lcm.worksetUid' in namespace 'plugin' not found in external property file. Have you forgotten to prefix the key with namespace in property file?
2024-05-16 12:38:59,395 ERROR Duplicate plugin ContactSystemPlugin
2024-05-16 12:39:00,104 ERROR The Display Key: AdminData.Role.Description.Claims_Non-Management_Ext is illegally formatted.  Please ensure that all Display Keys are a combination of alphanumeric, 'underscore', and 'dot' characters.
2024-05-16 12:39:00,546 ERROR The Display Key: AdminData.Role.Description.Claims_Non-Management_Ext is illegally formatted.  Please ensure that all Display Keys are a combination of alphanumeric, 'underscore', and 'dot' characters.
2024-05-16 12:39:01,012 ERROR The Display Key: AdminData.Role.Description.Claims_Non-Management_Ext is illegally formatted.  Please ensure that all Display Keys are a combination of alphanumeric, 'underscore', and 'dot' characters.
2024-05-16 12:39:01,079 ERROR [The Display Key: AdminData.Role.Description.Claims_Non-Management_Ext is illegally formatted.  Please ensure that all Display Keys are a combination of alphanumeric, 'underscore', and 'dot' characters., The Display Key: AdminData.Role.Description.Claims_Non-Management_Ext is illegally formatted.  Please ensure that all Display Keys are a combination of alphanumeric, 'underscore', and 'dot' characters.]
2024-05-16 12:39:01,079 WARN [The Display Key: AdminData.Role.Description.Claims_Non-Management_Ext is illegally formatted.  Please ensure that all Display Keys are a combination of alphanumeric, 'underscore', and 'dot' characters.]
2024-05-16 12:39:01,212 WARN The key 'lcm.worksetUid' in namespace 'plugin' not found in external property file. Have you forgotten to prefix the key with namespace in property file?
2024-05-16 12:39:11,236 INFO Config Change: AuthConfig{clientId='null', issuerUri='null', filterActive=false}
2024-05-16 12:39:14,107 INFO Migration Tool properties file C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\claimcenter\claimcenter\modules\configuration\config\cmt\cmt.properties loaded successfully
2024-05-16 12:39:19,438 INFO Decreased runlevel to 'GUIDEWIRE_STARTUP'
2024-05-16 12:39:19,440 ERROR ***** ClaimCenter unable to start *****
gw.pl.exception.GWLifecycleException: An exception was thrown attempting to enter NODAEMONS
at com.guidewire.pl.system.server.InitTab.increaseRunLevelTo(InitTab.java:682) ~[pl-50.10.2.jar:?]
at com.guidewire.pl.system.server.InitTab.setRunLevel(InitTab.java:384) ~[pl-50.10.2.jar:?]
at com.guidewire.pl.system.servlet.GuidewireStartupServlet.init(GuidewireStartupServlet.java:88) ~[pl-50.10.2.jar:?]
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$Wrapper.init(ServletHolder.java:1345) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.53.v20231009.jar:9.4.53.v20231009]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:632) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.53.v20231009.jar:9.4.53.v20231009]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:415) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.53.v20231009.jar:9.4.53.v20231009]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ServletHandler.java:750) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.53.v20231009.jar:9.4.53.v20231009]
at java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357) ~[?:?]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485) ~[?:?]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[?:?]
at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312) ~[?:?]
at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[?:?]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658) ~[?:?]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:774) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.53.v20231009.jar:9.4.53.v20231009]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.53.v20231009.jar:9.4.53.v20231009]

Anyone else have this problem or a similar one?  Thanks in advance.

Probably gonna need a little more of the stack trace to figure this out. Also what version of ClaimCenter are you using?

@SteveDrippsCentricConsulting OK, added that this is Jasper release, also some more stack trace.  Thanks.

Thanks Matt. I should have mentioned that there are often clues above the dreaded ERROR ***** ClaimCenter unable to start ***** line in the logs so it would be helpful to add some of those to your question as well

@SteveDrippsCentricConsulting  OK added more log chatter before the ***** ClaimCenter unable to start ***** message

Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might want to explore our sibling site [su], but please read their help pages before asking there (and please delete this off-topic post, and review our [help] before posting here again).

@tripleee Thanks for mentioning Super User, had no idea that was a site.  Anyway, are you familiar with GWCC's development environment/architecture?

@tripleee GWCC runs based largely on how it has been customized.  Customization is done with the Gosu language, based largely on Java.  It's entirely possible then that programmatic customizations to GWCC affect how it comes up, ie, successfully or not.  In this case the issue turned out to be that a customized plugin was running into (clashing with) another plug-in (in the GWCC context, a plug-in is a programmatic extension evoked by the server on startup to perform particular tasks either on startup or later when invoked by code).

My best guess is that ClaimCenter does not know what ContactSystemPlugin implementation to chose during startup and therefore cannot start.

What is the environment variable you are using when starting the server (-Denv if starting the server from the command line, the environment variable can be blank)
Does the ContactSystemPlugin.gwp file have more than one implementation specified for the environment variable you specified?

I'm afraid I probably couldn't provide a better answer without troubleshooting it next to you. If the answer ends up being something else please post the answer. Thanks.

ContactSystemPlugin had 2 plugins in it, one disabled.  I deleted the disabled one and voila, the server started up OK.  So we're good.
